# Scroll to a specific div in horizontal scrolling menu

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I am trying to achieve the following effect:

When you press on the `.page` div, the scrollbar will automatically scroll to it and that `.page` element will look like it's centered in `.pages` element

I tried stuff like `scrollIntoView()` and other methods but I couldn't achieve the right thing, `scrollIntoView()` simply shows you the element that you're pressing. What I want is a little different,  I want the scrollbar to **smoothly** scroll itself to the point where the chosen `.page` element is centered within the `.pages` div. (if the element does not have enough elements around it to be centered, its fine I just want the scrollbar to do its best..)

Here's the code pen: https://codepen.io/liana-webdev/pen/WNGdzQE

Also if you have an idea of how to simplify this code I'd be much thankful if you show that to me as well

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The `behaviour:smooth` option in `scrollIntoView()` function will help you smoothly scroll to the particular element. The `block:center` option is used to place the particular element in centre of the screen.

```
document.getElementById("id").scrollIntoView({
  behavior: smooth,
  block: center
});
```

Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) for more details.

Comment: thanks , this doesn't work immediately in my case because im working with a specific area, not the entire screen